# Big query error - "Unexpected. Please try again"

Tags: json, csv, gzip, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Big Query is unable to export table having 400k rows, it gives the erros - "Unexpected. Please try again"

I've tried -

1. gs://bucket/file.csv

Job ID: data-mind-679:job_rh4ddoiDkCipyFHV8d06EwS0K04

2. gs://bucket/file.csv.gzip

Job ID: data-mind-679:job_7HUNDA_vuu58xnrVdfgLBR-7Qtk

3. gs://bucket/file*.csv

Job ID: data-mind-679:job_z-RJqivfYQ_3IV_Qe7cUQg5mzAs

I already have all the files in JSON format, but I need them in CSV format

Comment: How long do they take those jobs before failing??

Comment: It fails as soon as I run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug affecting the availability of your table.  I've fixed the immediate issue and your table should be exportable now.  In the longer term, we're still working to fix the root cause of this issue so it won't happen again.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's still taking a lot of time to export though.

Comment: Hey Danny, I have kicked off some jobs, but they've been running for the past 20mins. Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: BigQuery doesn't currently support cancellation of jobs.  We're investigating ongoing slowness of extract jobs.  One suggestion is that exporting to GZIP CSV is observed to be faster than uncompressed CSV.  More discussion on https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=133